# Не очень понимаю принцип работы методов wait и notify класса Object

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

В статье о нём написано следующее:
Метод wait без аргументов
Заставляет текущий поток ждать, пока другой поток не вызовет метод notify() или метод notifyAll() для этого объекта. Другими словами, этот метод ведет себя точно так же, как если бы он просто выполнял вызов wait(0).
https://java-ru-blog.blogspot.com/2019/12/object-methods.html

есть код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();
        threadB.start();
        synchronized (threadB){
            try {
                threadB.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(threadB.total);
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
            total+=i;
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
/*        synchronized (this){
            notify();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Проблемы сразу две:

1. Поток работает до конца даже тогда, когда метод notify() закомментирован, что противоречит тому, что написано выше.
2. Если раскомментировать notify(), то не очень понятно, почему вызов этого метода находится внутри потока (каким образом поток пробудит сам себя)

Comment: Простой вопрос. Сколько в вашей программе потоков и какой из них должен быть заблокирован методом `threadB.wait();` ?

Comment: @tym32167, на сколько я понимаю, потока 2: main и Thread-0, блокировка происходит в главном потоке (хотя я могу ошибаться)

Comment: Верно. А какой из потоков дорабатывает до конца, если закомментировать notify?

Comment: @tym32167, это уже сложнее, конечный вывод происходит в главном потоке, но, чтобы это произошло, должен полностью пройти цикл в Thread-0, поэтому, рискну предположить, что Thread-0 ко времени вывода заканчивает свою работу полностью

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Поток работает до конца даже тогда, когда метод notify() закомментирован

Документации к методу wait написано:

> interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:

> ```
> synchronized (obj) {
>     while (<condition does not hold>)
>         obj.wait();
>     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
> }
> ```

и это идиоматический способ использовать `wait` - всегда в цикле, и проверять условие до и после вызова `wait`. Т.к. у вас пример синтетический, то трудно сказать, что здесь будет условием. Для классического примера publish-subscribe на стороне подписчика условие ожидания будет `пока нет входящих сообщений`.

Если суммировать, то проблема в spurious wakeup, т.е. в беспричинном пробуждении. Т.е. `wait` может вернуть управление, даже если не было `notify`.

> не очень понятно, почему вызов этого метода находится внутри потока

Ну это вы так написали :) Обычно для ожидания не используют объекты `Thread`, а используют другие объекты. Часто это разделяемый между потоками объект и его же и используется для передачи уведомления. В том же примере с `publish`-`subscribe` это может быть очередь, через которую передаются уведомления.

Смотрите адекватный пример хотя бы [тут](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html)

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

я не супер спец в java, но я предположу, что особенностью класса Thread может быть вызов Notify когда поток прекратил выполнение. То есть, в вашем коде, сначала останавливается главный поток, потом дочерний выполняет свою работу и как он закончит, он сам вызовет notify и без вашего участия, чем разблокирует основной поток. Чтобы эту теорию проверить, попробуйте закомментировать это threadB.start(); и ваша программа должна зависнуть, так как дочерний поток никогда не завершит работу (ведь он её даже не начал), а значит он никогда не разблокирует основной поток.

Чтобы провести более чистый эксперимент, давайте лочить не объект потока, а просто какой то другой объект. Например

```
class Solution {

    public static Object syncRoot = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();
        threadB.start();
        synchronized (syncRoot) {
            try {
                syncRoot.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(threadB.total);


    }
}


class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            total += i;
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (Solution.syncRoot) {
            Solution.syncRoot.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Я думаю, тут, если закомментировать строку `Solution.syncRoot.notify();` то программа ожидаемо зависнет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!